# Ubuntu: Restringir acesso FTP/SFTP de usuário para uma pasta existente

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

Considere a seguinte situação em um servidor web montado no UBUNTU:

```
/var/www/site 1  <-- apenas root
/var/www/site 2  <-- designer 1, root
/var/www/site 3  <-- designer 2, root
/var/www/site 4  <-- designer 1, root
```

Significando que o usuário `root` tem acesso a todas as pastas, `designer 1` acessa as pastas `/site 2` e `/site 4` e `designer 2` acessa apenas a pasta `/site 3`.

Atualmente, as pastas já existem e são acessadas pelo `root` normalmente, só que agora os designers precisam ter acesso a pastas especificas dos projetos que trabalham.

Como faço para criar **novos usuários** que possam acessar pastas especificas **já existentes** do servidor?

Note que não tem problema se tiver que criar um usuário para cada pasta a ser restringida. Neste caso e considerando o exemplo acima, o `designer 1` teria os dados de acesso às duas pastas: `/site 2` e `/site 4`. Desde que cada um tenha acesso a seus projetos, mas não aos dos outros colaboradores, está tudo certo.

Comment: 1 dica, use um servidor de ftp, como o **proftpd**.
Caso queira usar sftp devera trabalhar com grupos de usuários, sendo a administração um pouco mais complexa do que usar um servidor ftp como mencionei acima.

Comment: A dica seria boa, mas não é viável usar um servidor FTP. Se fosse, não teria feito a pergunta.

Comment: Então crie grupos de usuários, dando permissões pelo grupo. Ex:

Grupo 1 tem permissão nos diretórios **site 2** e **site 4**
Grupo 2 tem permissão nos diretórios **site 3** e **site 1**

depois basta ir adicionando os usuários que deseja conceder permissões ao grupo em questão, Ex:

cria o usuário fulano e o adicione ao **grupo 1**, ele terá permissões nos diretórios do grupo 1. Só ir adicionando usuários, criando grupos conforme sua necessidade.

Comment: @AlessandroSchneider, sim, exatamente isso, mas eu já sabia. Não coloquei na pergunta porque poderia haver outra solução, e não queria direcionar nem restringir a resposta. De qualquer maneira, estou perguntando justamente como fazer, ou seja, quais os comandos. Se souber, por gentileza, responda a pergunta.